# JavaFX: Disabling TableView multi-column sorting

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I need my `TableView` to have all its columns sortable, but I do not want it to be multi-column sortable through shift-clicking the columns. Is there any way to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a listener to the `sortOrder` property of your `TableView`, which is an `ObservableList`, and check that this list never has more than one entry:

```
myTableView.getSortOrder().addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends TableColumn> c) -> {
    while (myTableView.getSortOrder().size() > 1) {
        myTableView.getSortOrder().remove(1);
    }
});
```

However, note that this approach invalidates the `Change` object for all subsequent listeners. Therefore, if you have other listeners for the `sortOrder` property, you might want to use this approach:

```
myTableView.setOnSort(sortEvent -> {
    while (myTableView.getSortOrder().size() > 1) {
        myTableView.getSortOrder().remove(1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the second option works great. The first option is less elegant because that is probably causing the change listener to go into some kind of unnecessary loop.